# Google Sheet npm package Update sheet with sorted data (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api, npm-package

I am getting data from a form on HTTP request and before writing it on the sheet I want to sort the sheet. I have fetched the google sheet rows and sorted them w.r.t date but the issue is I am unable to overwrite the google sheet with the sorted data.

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('<Google Sheet ID>');
        
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
      client_email: '<client email>',
      private_key: "<Private Key>",
});

await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
        
const sheet = doc.sheetsById[0]; // or use doc.sheetsByIndex[index]
const rows = await sheet.getRows();
rows.sort(function(o){ return new Date( -o.Timestamp ) });
```

This is how I am sorting data. I am using Google Sheet Npm Package. Can anyone guide me on how to write rows on a google sheet with newly sorted data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [following package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) your could use the [save()](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-row?id=fn-save) method to save your updates as explained on their [documentation](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/?id=working-with-rows).